# How to design the following layout:

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments

I need to design the following layout:

[image]

Now what you see here is this:

In the left part I have a `ScrollView`. In it I have a combination of 2 `TextView`s that a `Button`/`ImageButton` (the red one) is attached to them.

Now those combinations of two `TextView`s and a red `Button` buttons can have different icons and need to be added dynamically.

On the right side there are other views that pop up and disappear when the red buttons in the left `ScrollView` are clicked. So depending on what button was clicked you could open a list or a `DatePicker` or a box with a `TextView`, accept and reject buttons (shown in the right top corner).

After I make my choice in the right view this will affect the `TextView` next to the button that called the view on the left.

Finally the red button at the most right bottom corner will submit my choices to the server and will take me to the next step after I receive my response.

Now for the question:

For the right part it's understood to me that I have to use `Fragment`s. But should I use `Fragment`s for the left side as well? Or this is an overkill and I should just drop it as a `TextView` and a `LinearLayout` with `TextView` and a `Button`?

What are the advantages of using `Fragment`s in this situation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--if you don't use a Fragment for the left side, what would you put the LinearLayout in?

Comment: I could just create a ScrollView in it add a LinearLayout and in it programatilcy add a TextView and then add another LinearLayout with horizontal orientation and in it add another TextView with a button. and of course change the icon progrematicly as well. and so on for as much of this object as I need...

Comment: You could create a ScrollView in what? Your original Fragment? That's what I'm not quite understanding.

Comment: In my FragmentActivity LinearLayout.

Comment: Have you tried implementing this ?

Comment: I still think what is the direction I should go with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the left you have a ListView. Have an adapter for the ListView. In the getView() method of the adapter, you could have a layout that would have something like this :

```
<LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
    <TextView >
    <LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView />
        <ImageButton />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The getCount() method of the adapter would be the # of times you want this pattern to repeat.

Comment: Thanks, man... I ended up using a ListView and it solved my problem.